# How to merge Two manifest file in Unity3D 2017

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, google-play-services, android-manifest, googleads-mobile-unity

I have two manifest files in my Unity

One is for Google Play Game Services

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!-- This file was automatically generated by the Google Play Games plugin for Unity
     Do not edit. -->
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.google.example.games.mainlibproj"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="8" android:targetSdkVersion="16" />


    <application>



        <!-- The space in these forces it to be interpreted as a string vs. int -->
        <meta-data android:name="com.google.android.gms.games.APP_ID"
            android:value="\ 466669193109" />

        <!-- Keep track of which plugin is being used -->
        <meta-data android:name="com.google.android.gms.games.unityVersion"
            android:value="\ 0.9.50" />

        <activity android:name="com.google.games.bridge.NativeBridgeActivity"
            android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Translucent.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen" />
    </application>
</manifest>
```

And

One if for Google Mobile Ads

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!--
This Google Mobile Ads plugin library manifest will get merged with your
application's manifest, adding the necessary activity and permissions
required for displaying ads.
-->
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.google.unity.ads"
    android:versionName="1.0"
    android:versionCode="1">
  <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="14"
      android:targetSdkVersion="19" />
  <application>
  </application>
</manifest>
```

When I try to build my android application

I get this error

[image]

I tried to solve it by Deleting the Google Mobile Ads Manifest

but then it says missing the manifest

I tried to merged them also but again failed

I am really stuck

Comment: It is not a manifest merge problem but several instance of the same libs or something like that. Basically you have two .jar or .aar files with same functions (SmsRetriever in this case). And you should remove one of them. Maybe someone can explain it more clearly

Comment: where I can find .jar or .aar files

Comment: In the Plugins folder. But I'm afraid you have to figure out yourself what should be deleted